# How to download an offsite file and add it to my database in Django with celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to do the following with django and celery. Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing

```
@task        
def dl_and_save_to_documents(document_pk):
        document = Document.objects.get(pk=document_pk)
        f = urlopen("some/url/etc/file.pdf")
        document.pdf_file=f
        document.save()
```

No errors are returned but pdf_file remains null. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the same code work without using Celery?  You should first establish that.  `urlopen` returns a file-like object, not the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different file retrieval method. I.e. urllib.urlretrieve().

Answer (score 0):

Try [grab](http://grablib.org/) instead of urllib. It gives you nice wrapper around cURL lib, actually it's headless browser but currently w/o JS support.